# Generate a sequence of letters in Python

Tags: python, r, letter

Is there a built-in method / module in Python to generate letters such as the built-in constant LETTERS or letters constant in R?

The R built-in constant works as `letters[n]` where if `n = 1:26` the lower-case letters of the alphabet are produced.

Thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's called [`string.ascii_lowercase`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase).

If you wanted to pick *n* many random lower case letters, then:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
from random import choice

letters = [choice(ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(5)]
```

If you wanted it as a string, rather than a list then use `str.join`:

```
letters = ''.join([choice(ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(5)])
```

Comment: I had the link on the clipboard while composing my unposted answer :)

Comment: @Tichodroma, @jon-clements - thanks. This is nice. I can easily pass a sequence to it such as `string.ascii_letters[1:5]`. However, is there a way to generate a series of random letters that are evaluated from an expression producing random integers between 0 and 26? When I try with an array  result from `string.ascii_letters[np.random.randint(0,26,10)]` it tells me I can only have one element converted to an index.

Comment: @John that's a new question, and is about subsetting in python. Python is not R!

Comment: @ John -- use random.sample(string.ascii_letters,5)

Comment: More generally, Python tends to use "list comprehension" when R is magically vectorised.

Comment: @Spacedman - ah-ha! `[string.ascii_letters[i] for i in np.random.random_integers(0,26,5)]`

Comment: @John I'd go for `[random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in range(5)]` but I suppose if you want to use `numpy` to generate the numbers then index into the list that's fine :)

Comment: @John I've updated the answer to reflect examples of how to produce either a list or a string of *n* random lower case letters

Comment: @JonClements - that is a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 20):

You can use `map` as in the following:

```
>>> map(chr, range(65, 91))
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
>>> map(chr, range(97, 123))
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
>>> a = map(chr, range(65, 70))
>>> a
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
```

Answer (score 9):

With list comprehensions and reference from the above, there is another method:

```
>>> [chr(x) for x in range(97, 123)]
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way to do it which will give you directly a string:

```
>>> bytearray(range(97,123)).decode("utf-8")
u'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

(it works with both python2 and python3, of course the u prefix won't be visible if it's python 3)

You can obviously tranform that string into a list like in other answers if that is what you prefer, for instance with:

```
>>> [x for x in bytearray(range(97,123)).decode("utf-8")]
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

It is also very easy to change it to pick n random letters (repetition allowed):

```
>>> import random
>>> n = 10
>>> bytearray(random.randint(97, 122) for x in range(n)).decode('utf-8')
'qdtdlrqidx'
```

Or without repetition:

```
>>> import random
>>> n = 10
>>> bytearray(random.sample(range(97, 123),n)).decode('utf-8')
'yjaifemwbr'
```

Answer (score 0):

More readable for many would be

```
map(chr, range(ord("A"), ord("Z"))
```